# How to install specific version of Go in Ubuntu using snap

Tags: golang

I am trying to install Go version 1.16 using a snap package, but not able to. Instead I am getting newer versions.

How can I install version 1.16 regardless of what version is currently available?

Comment: if you want stable one sudo snap install --stable go --classic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. you can run snap info go, which gives you a list of go versions.

   ```
   sudo snap info go
   ```
2. Then you can install your preferred version with --channel like this.

   ```
   sudo snap install go --channel=1.16/stable --classic
   ```

This will also work for upgrade / downgrade to specific version after installation. For example you want to downgrade from 1.17 go version to 1.16

```
sudo snap refresh go --channel=1.16/stable --classic
```